# How can a array value or an object be copied to another variable without copying its reference in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

How can an array value or an object be copied to another variable without copying its reference in Javascript so that the copied value and variable can be manipulated independently, without causing any change to the original one?

Comment: For arrays, you can do `array.slice(0);`

Comment: You need to deep clone the object. Also show your attempt as well by using `<>`.

Comment: Did you mean [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)?

Comment: You can refer this link for deep copy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript

Answer (score -2):

Array coping by value:

```
var array = [1,2,3];
var newArr = array.slice();
```

and Object coping by value:

```
var obj = {name : "A"};
var new_obj = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: If this is the correct answer, we should look for similar posts and mark it as duplicate. Also, `json.stringify` will remove functions

Comment: You further want to run `new_obj` through `JSON.parse` after `JSON.stringify`

Comment: The first one only creates a shallow copy.

Comment: @Rajesh I know JSON.stringify remove functions. but I think u not read the question. :- LOL

Comment: @Sandeep First, please mind the tone. Second, any data in question is a sample data. Actual data is always more complex. Third, when you answer, make sure you answer in a way you cover obvious issues.

Comment: @Sandeep does slice() works for multi-dimensional array too?

Comment: @raosaeedali No. inner objects will again be assigned using reference. Instead of asking a generic question, my suggestion is to put a specific one with proper use-case.

Comment: @Sandeep alright and thanks btw. :)